# ml model deployment on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk, gcloud, google-ai-platform

I have a ml model deployed on gcp that runs every time a file is dropped in gcs, however, I am not 100% sure what each command did to make it happen. Below is my step.

1. create a docker image that contains a python module I want to run.
2. push the image to gcr.
3. run the below command (which I do not know exactly what it does

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training my_model
  --master-image-uri gcr.io/my-project-name/my-image-name
```

then I created a yml file on gitlab with details such as trigger-event.

Can someone tell me what this `gcloud ...` does?

Google only describes it as *gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training - submit an AI Platform training job* and I do not know what it means.

Comment: There is a dedicated [chapter](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/using-containers) in the documentation teaching how to build/deploy and submitting the [training job](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs) for custom ML containers. Does it answer you question?

Answer (score 0):

This is google cloud commands you Read this to get more clarity [gcloud Sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud)